# Error while installing hello_world plugin on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: frama-c

I've installed frama-c using opam (on Ubuntu 16.04). 
I try to install the "hello_world.ml" as plugin (of the plugin development guide) using a Makefile

```
    FRAMAC_SHARE :=$(shell frama-c.byte -print-path)
    FRAMAC_LIBDIR :=$(shell frama-c.byte -print-libpath)
    PLUGIN_NAME = Hello
    PLUGIN_CMO = hello_word
    include $(FRAMAC_SHARE)/Makefile.dynamic
```

Running make, I get this:

```
     /home/amira/.opam/system/share/frama-c/Makefile.dynamic:295: .depend: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
     /home/amira/.opam/system/share/frama-c/Makefile.plugin:204: *** "The file 'Hello.mli' must be provided. The simplest workaround is 'touch Hello.mli'.". Arrêt.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you try the indications of the second warning (`touch Hello.mli`)?

Comment: `Hello.mli` is not created. But after running `make` I get this 
`Ocamldep     ./.depend
Generating   META.frama-c-hello
make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « hello_word.cmo », nécessaire pour « Hello.cmi ». Arrêt.`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to follow the advice:

```
"The file 'Hello.mli' must be provided. The simplest workaround is 'touch Hello.mli'
```

The message `.depend: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type` is not an error. It is an artefact of a `include .depend` that will be generated automatically. Gnu make will restart automatically after building it to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

I run `touch Hello.mli` and then I run `make` and I get this :

```
Ocamldep     ./.depend
Generating   META.frama-c-hello
make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « hello_word.cmo », nécessaire pour « Hello.cmi ». Arrêt.
```

Comment: Instead of an answer, please edit your question to reflect the current issue. In addition, you should also give us the list of files that exist in your directory. If you have followed section 2.2.4, you should have an  `hello_world.ml` file together with the `Makefile`. In addition, section 2.2.5 explicitely says that `Hello.mli` is required.

Comment: My directory contains : Hello.cmi  Hello_DEP  Hello.mli  hello_world.ml  Makefile  META.frama-c-hello

Comment: And what is the content of your `Makefile`? When I run `make` in a directory that contains `Makefile`, `Hello.mli` and `hello_world.ml` from p17 and 18 of the manual on a machine with Magnesium installed, everything is fine.